# Calculating distance in matrices Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Trying to calculate Pearson Coefficient for a big matrix (e.g. 300000x12000)

So I'm doing next:

Import libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
```

Do the dummy table using pd.get_dummies:

```
table=pd.get_dummies(data['word'])
```

Creating empty matrix using DataFrame:

```
data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=table.columns,columns=table.columns)
```

Then doing calculation of pearsonr using for loops for the matrix:

```
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
        data_ibs.ix[i,j] =  pearsonr(table.ix[:,i],table.ix[:,j]) [0]
```

It works but *waaay* to slow - it worked for 4 hours and still calculates. Is there another possibility to do that?

Thanks in advance, I'll appreciate your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use [`corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), which uses pearson as the default method:

```
table.corr()
```

For example:

```
np.random.seed(0)

>>> pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5)).corr()
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000  0.029861  0.077225  0.905577 -0.254004
1  0.029861  1.000000 -0.548770 -0.394760 -0.868972
2  0.077225 -0.548770  1.000000  0.297952  0.819027
3  0.905577 -0.394760  0.297952  1.000000  0.129641
4 -0.254004 -0.868972  0.819027  0.129641  1.000000
```